# ACCESS VBA Unmatched Records Query Not Working When Concatenating

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been trying to run a query from MS ACCESS VBA. My query works well when I don't add concatenated fields. When I use a concatenated field like in the code below, it turns an empty result.

Is there any work around?

```
lstStudentName.RowSource = "SELECT [sdtName] & ' ' & [sdtFatherName] & ' ' & [sdtLastName] AS sdtFullName, sdtID FROM tbl_sdt_Info " & _
   " LEFT join tbl_sdt_Rounds ON tbl_sdt_Info.sdtID = tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID " & _
   " WHERE IS NULL(tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't get anything because using IS NULL incorrectly. Either `IsNull(tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID)` or `tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID IS NULL`. The latter is preferable because it is SQL, IsNull() is a VBA function.

Comment: Most would make sdtID the first field and set ColumnWidths as 0";1.0" and set first column as BoundColumn. This will allow viewing and typing first letter of name but sdtID will be listbox value.

Comment: It worked, however it is giving me all records from both tables. It is not excluding records with the WHERE condition ! Any suggestions please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your SQL:

1. Incorrect use of IS NULL - should be either `IsNull(tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID)` or `tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID IS NULL`. The latter is preferable because it is SQL, IsNull() is a VBA function.
2. Since there are two sdtID fields, query shouldn't work without table prefix to specify field. I am surprised you get anything.
3. Although possibly not an issue as is, my preference would be to make sdtID the first field and set ColumnWidths as 0";1.0" and first column as BoundColumn. This will allow viewing and typing first letter of name but sdtID will be listbox value.

Never hurts to build and test query object and when it works, replicate SQL statement in VBA.

```
lstStudentName.RowSource = "SELECT  tbl_sdt_Info.sdtID, sdtName & ' ' & sdtFatherName & ' ' & sdtLastName AS sdtFullName FROM tbl_sdt_Info " & _
   "LEFT join tbl_sdt_Rounds ON tbl_sdt_Info.sdtID = tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID " & _
   "WHERE tbl_sdt_Rounds.sdtID IS NULL;"
```